# ipad programming guidance

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm just at the startup level in ipad/iphone programming. There is a project in my mind, but I need some guidance on key points:

fundemental requirements:
1)user interface and interaction like wired magazine app(playing movies on page,etc)
2)accessing the timeuser spent on pages and videos
more:
-accessing another application's data (and let's say that application can give permission, if there is so)

Maybe these are just easy things to figure out, but if you could point me where to look I would be pleased.

PS: I have more than 10+ top seller ebooks on ipad/ios/iphone programming and I'm started to reading them. To be clear, names of these concepts (in what way I should research accessing the time user spent on a page- I did try on google on my own words but could not get the desired result)or some material pointing the issues really ease my way.

Comment: There are many books to learn iPhone/iPad development, and the most famous ones are quite good. But please, learn Objective-C first, otherwise you'll get only frustrations. And if you don't know C, learn C first or you'll pollute discussion forums and Q&A sites with questions that will annoy people. Believe me, I've got quite an experience with that :)

Comment: I learnt C++ first, then Objective-C, then C. Is also a possibility. :)

Comment: I have background in C,C++,Java,etc. so directly started from sample app developments from books, and read appendix parts related objective-c language. I rather get my hands dirty while learning the language :)

Answer (score 0):

The UI portion of your question should be pretty easy to get to, it will just take learning a lot of the Cocoa Touch library, probably even a bit of Core Foundation.

There are two books I highly recommend:

- [Programming iOS 4](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920010258/)
- [iPhone Programming: Big Nerd Ranch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706242)

I strongly recommend Programming iOS 4, primarily because it has been updated for XCode 4.

---

To answer your other question: to the best of my knowledge, you are not allowed to access other application's data due to sandboxing. You can, however, share data between your own apps if they share the same App ID.

Answer (score 0):

First, as to the question on sharing data between apps. You can pass data between apps - basically launching one app from another and passing arguments. This can go both ways. If this is what you want, I'll share more on that.

As to learning, I recommend devouring Apple's documents, their samples, and Stackoverflow. Most of the iPhone development books you come across on development will be useful.

Comment: Are you suggesting the thing like opening a pdf in mail and sending it to another pdf reader app? I need precisely this: there is an app like interactive magazine and in my app i need to know did the user watch video, how much time did the user spent on which page. So in my app user's activity can seen in a detailed way. The other app can give me any permission but our Apple ID's not same. @Ryan Wersal